# How do I use a if statement to access values in a dictionary based on the corresponding key?

Tags: python, dictionary

I thought I could use a dictionary to store key/value pairs for user's names and passwords. How do I use a if statement to access values in a dictionary based on the corresponding key?

```
users_data_base = dict(Mike = "Speedy203", Ken = "Justify30", Marvin = "Pop_Jay")
while True:
    current_user = input("Enter User Name: ")
    if current_user not  in users_data_base:
        print("User name not valid")
    else:
        
        print("Welcome " + current_user)
        break
while True:
    pw_entry = input("Please enter password: ")
    if pw_entry is ([current_user]):
        print("Incorrect password entry")
        print("Try again")
    else:
        print("Successful entry")
        break
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem with this code?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean. An `if` statement doesn't access values in a dictionary. It executes some code if a condition is true.

Comment: My apologies, maybe I wasn't clear. I wanted the code to access the (V) in the dictionary as the password for the user name(K)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the dictionary's name in the second `if`:

```
if pw_entry == user_data_base[current_user]:
    # Here ----^
```

Comment: Thanks very much. That was great.